# WSO2 IS Challenge Question Evaluation Case-Sensitivity, Configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Trying to find out whether WSO2 Identity Server (IS) requires case-sensitivity by default when evaluating challenge question answers in password reset requests.  If not, is there a configuration flag to enable/disable case-sensitivity or any other configuration to enforce or not require case-sensitive challenge question answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code level, the answer user provide will be converted to lowercase and then hashed[1] This hashed value will be compared with the stored value. So as an answer to your question challenge question answers of the user is not case-sensitive.Also, there is no configuration to make it so  OOTB.

[1].https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/824fa6505eeabcf50de13bb2272e586f7e34ff25/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/recovery/ChallengeQuestionManager.java#L760